# Sed regex multiline matching based on start, end and content

Tags: html, regex, sed

I'm sure the example is out there, but having trouble finding it.

In thousands of static HTML files, I have a block of code as follows and I'm needing to swap out different AdSense code blocks with unique content:

```
<div id="left">

    <div style="margin-top:1px;">
    <script type="text/javascript"><!--
    google_ad_client = "pub-123456132654";
    google_ad_slot = "9844984";
    google_ad_width = 468;
    google_ad_height = 15;
    //-->
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
    </script>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="content">
<div id="googlesquare">
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
google_ad_client = "pub-123456132654";
google_ad_slot = "68468464";
google_ad_width = 300;
google_ad_height = 250;
//-->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
</script>
</div>
```

I have found some patterns which would match start and end for sed usage, but am missing the  inner content matching.

I'm not tied to sed if it is better done in another CLI tool, but as common a Unix tool as possible is preferred.

**Update**

Here is what I would like to be able to capture with one pattern, without grabbing the others:

[image]

Comment: Every user on SO is going to come in here and lecture you about regex and HTML. I'll post up the regex in a sec. :P

Comment: what's the expected output for the example?

Comment: yep, if I was in a DOM-savvy domain, then would not want regex, but needed in a bash process, where ideally, I'd like to be able to do such things quickly (if not efficiently) when they arise.

Comment: @poiu2000, updated original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed -n '
\|<script type="text/javascript">|,\|</script>| {
    H
    \|</script>| {
       s/.*//
       x
       s/google_ad_client = "pub-123456132654";/&/
       t catch
       b nocatch

: catch
# catch code here
    s/pub-123456132654/nopub-9876543210/
    p
# end of catch block
       b
       }
  }

\|<script type="text/javascript">|,\|</script>| !{
: nocatch
# no catch code here
   p
# end of no catch block
   }
' YourFile
```

Catch the section and allow you to act on it (all the section is in the working buffer at this time so line a separated by \n ). For the purpose of sample, i just change the `pub-123456132654` to `nopub-9876543210` and no other action is made on the file.

A new line is added when a section is find. It's possible to remove it if mandatory

**Some explaination**

`\|`in \||` is used to change the default separator (/) with another (|) more interesting in this case due to <**/**s

The `\|</script>| {` into `\|<script type="text/javascript">|,\|</script>| {` block is used to occuring at last line of the block like $ occur on last line of the file.

In this sub block, the working and holding buffer are exchanged (goal is to get holfing into working buffer and have a empty holding buffer for next iteration)

The sed workflow is a bit strange with `b` and `t` due to fact that `t` (like an *if goto*) only work after a s// that occur (missing the *else* or *not*)

Comment: oh, how wonderful sed is! This solves the problem at hand and gives me another useful tool for text processing, thanks!

Comment: if possible, could you please add some more inline comments to explain what is happening? ie, why the `\` before the pipe delimiter each time? In the man pages, it does not seem to be necessary. Also, the line `\|</script>| {`, why does it match the end script tag again after already ammending the target code block into the buffer? The s,x,s,t,b block looks to clear the buffer, then stores the match(es). Loving sed still, but scratching head a bit :)

Comment: i adapt the answer, including comment

Comment: Highly appeciated! Thanks for taking the time

Answer (score 1):

### Regex

`<script[^>]*>(.*?)</script>`

### Notes

- Anything between the tags is stored into the first capturing group.
- **Does NOT properly match tags nested inside themselves.**

Comment: could you please show me how to adjust that for a certain had-coded container value, ie `google_ad_slot = "9844984";`?

Comment: You would need to specify additional regex within the first capture group which is currently matching everything: `(.*?)` For example: `<script[^>]*>(.*?(?:google_ad_slot[ ="]{4}(\d+)";).*?)</script>`. You would then use the second capture group... In this instance it matches `9844984`.

Comment: Do you need to match the entire tags, wouldn't it be easier just to match those hard coded container values?

Comment: I need to match the whole tags and replace them with something like `#ADBLOCK_UNIQUE_1234#`. My target block I would like to capture with one regex is here: http://i.imgur.com/Duif8ax.png

Comment: Could you give an example of the full output that you want to create?

Comment: What I want to replace it with should be irrelevant to being able to capture the string. Once I have it captured, then I'm fine to replace it.